# Div contents (Pie Chart, Progress Bars) are not reflecting in Print Window

Tags: javascript, php

i have generated Pie Chart and Progress Bars Using Jquery and Some Css.
But when i try to print that particular div with simple JS function, text values are reflecting properly but shape/size are not reflecting on Print Window.

here is my Pie Chart Div Image:

[image]

here is that div when im trying to print it :(Print Result)

[image]

My Simple JS function for print is :

```
function printdiv()
{       
    var newstr=document.getElementById("reportBody").innerHTML;
    //reportBody div contains this graph
    var header='<header><div align="center"><h3 style="color:#EB5005">  </h3></div><br></header><hr><br>'
    //var footer='<footer class="footer1" id="footer">footer</footer> '
    var footer ="";

    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write('<html> <body onload="window.print()">'+ newstr + '</html>' + footer);
    popupWin.document.close(); 
    return false;
}
```

So how to get that color portion in my print div or i need to convert that div into Image and then print it? Even same problem is occur when im trying to print progress bar too.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to include your css and js in print windows as well. As I see you pass markup only.

You should also give [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) a try